# Restructure list during Import

Tags: list-manipulation, import

I am continuously importing a text file which is written by another program and read in Mathematica. The text file gets updated in chunks, meaning that the text file is augmented by a certain number of lines every n second. Mathematica puts all those chunks in one big list.

I wanted to know if I can make Mathematica automatically make a list of list of those chunks?

like : {{chunk1},{chunk2},{chunk3},...}

all of that during the import... 
hence Mathematica has to understand that the file has increased in size and add only the new values as a new list to an existing list (AppendTo) ... this is how I can see a solution, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Can't speak for everyone here, but I'd like some more detail/clarification: (1) What have you tried so far? (2) If I follow, something generates the text file while the Mathematica program reading it runs - correct?  (3) What determines the chuncks (time, the n seconds? number of lines or bits? arbitrariness? availability of the text input? other?).  You may need to keep a record of the total length of the text file at each chunk and then simply grab the last chunk as a list and append it to the growing list of lists.

Comment: I am not completely sure but you can give this a try: If you open the file with `stream = OpenRead[file]` you can use `ReadList` to read all data present. After the other program has written new data to the file, the `stream` object should still point to the old location and you should be able to use `ReadList` (or some of its siblings) again in order to read to the new data... Don't forget to `Close` the `stream` in the end.